# imo.im remain logged in (remember me)

Tags: chat, cookies

I am a frequent user of imo.im and use its google chrome plugin too. But since few days i am unable to use its autologin feature as they have removed the option in login page. So i have to log in everytime i turn on google chrome. Anyone have any idea if the Remember me option will be available ever again or not. Please suggest any ways by editing the cookies. I tried by setting all the sites session cookies to a far date, but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Remember Me' feature is supported on the new UI: http://imo.im/new

Comment: yeah.....ur true...already using that :)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider using [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oeoibdmcpaofjgcdncagknlmlmngkgfm) for sites which do not support autologin.

Comment: tried it, this extenstion does not works with imo.im, the forms are generated with javascript (yui), hence the pass is not auto saved and autocomplete wiht form do not work

Comment: Whatever extension it was, it appears to have been removed from the Chrome Web Store.